# create a new Jenkins job by using Process DSL plugin groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I need to create a Jenkins new job by copying the configurations from an existing maven project.
I wanted to do this via a groovy script and using the I have Process DSL plugin. I have written the below script which is able to create a new job but I am getting an issue with the GIT SSH URL

```
String gitRepository = 'ssh://git@stash.abc.com:1111/cegp/abc-automation-test'
String buildBranch = 'develop'
String projectName = 'APMSmokeTesting'
String credentialIDGithub = '61668d1b-3336-4c4d-90d7-721017049e36'


// job definition
mavenJob(projectName) {
    logRotator {
        numToKeep(20)
    }
    wrappers {
        preBuildCleanup()
    }
    description('Build the Java project: ' + gitRepository)
    
    scm {
        git {
            branch(buildBranch)
            remote {
                github (gitRepository)
                credentials(credentialIDGithub)
            }
        }
    }
    
    triggers {
        scm('@daily')
    }
    wrappers {
        goals('clean verify -Dtags="APMSmokeTesting"')
    }
}
```

As per the above configuration, in the new job **Source code Management** the **Repository URL** should be ssh://git@stash.abc.com:1111/cegp/abc-automation-test.git as I need to do an SSH only.
But the above script is population **Repository URL** filed as **https://github.com/**ssh://git@stash.abc.com:1111/cegp/abc-automation-test/ which is wrong.
Could you please help me to resolve the same.

Comment: Do you need to create a new job during runtime?

Comment: Yes, I will read a file to get the Job names/ Whatever job name I will get I will create jobs using the same names

Comment: Please add more details about your requirement. When you create a new job based on file, what is the difference between the original job and the copied job? I am trying to understand if for sake of varying `parameters` between the two jobs you really  need to make a job copy. There may be other ways to achieve what you need. Some considerations- Jobs may be nested in many folders so you are trying to `query` jenkins to `find` the right job and the making a copy of the `config.xml` into a new job with a new name. Is this your requirement?

Comment: It will grat if it can be done by Process Job DSLs also

Comment: No, In simple words I am explaining my requirement. I wanted to automate the Jenkins Job creation process, it can be done by Process Job DSLs by adding the groovy script. I need to create a job that will download code from BitBucket and run the test cases of the project. As I am having many projects I wanted to automate the manual job creation steps. Could you please help to write the script which will download the project from BitBucket using an SSH key. Plz refer the URL for reference :
https://docs.d2iq.com/mesosphere/dcos/services/jenkins/3.5.3-2.150.1/script-template-job-dsl/

Comment: I am trying some as below but I am unable to clone the project from bitbucket: // use the github-ci-key credentials for authentication with GitHub
job('example-1') {
    scm {
        git {
            remote {
                github('account/repo', 'ssh')
                credentials('github-ci-key')
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Thanks for the details. As per the link, is your seed job i.e., `Freestyle` job able to clone from bitbucket? If yes, you need to first setup the `scm checkout` stage inside a normal pipeline job and then get into the job copy work.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion worked. Thanks !!
 pipeline jon

Comment: Good to know! Please provide more details on what worked and how you fixed it and mark this question closed.

Comment: From a pipeline job I am unable to create a new Job, it seems it can be done by only Process DSL

Comment: As per my new findings, I have updated the post. Now I am getting only one issue here. As per the configuration, in the new job Source code Management, the Repository URL should be ssh://git@stash.abc.com:1111/cegp/abc-automation-test.git as I need to do an SSH only and providing a key. But the above script is population Repository URL filed as github.com/ssh://git@stash.abc.com:1111/cegp/… which is wrong. The extra getting added to the URL is github.com which is not required

Comment: Solved !!! Use url instead of github. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Working code to automate job creation in Jenkins:

    String gitRepository = 'ssh://git@stash.abc.com:<port>/cegp/gsc-automation-test'
    String buildBranch = 'develop'
    String projectName = 'APMSmokeTesting'
    String credentialIDGithub = '61668d1b-3336-4c4d-90d7-721017049e36'

    
    // job definition
    mavenJob(projectName) {
        logRotator {
            numToKeep(20)
        }
        wrappers {
            preBuildCleanup()
        }
        description('Build the Java project: ' + gitRepository)
        
        scm {
            git {
                branch(buildBranch)
                remote {
                    url (gitRepository)
                    credentials(credentialIDGithub)
                }
            }
        }
        
        triggers {
            scm('@daily')
        }
        wrappers {
            goals('clean verify -Dtags="APMSmokeTesting"')
        }
    }
```